# Connecting to remote MySQL server in Altova DatabaseSpy

Tags: mysql, sql, altova

I'm trying to use Altova DatabaseSpy to connect to my remote MySQL server as a data source. I'm getting an error though

[image]

Here are the menus I'm going through:

[image: Menu 1]

[image: Menu 2]

[image: Menu 3]

[image: Client Configuration (under Menu 3)]

I'm using the same port/user/password as when I connect with Django, but it's not working. I also tried using ApexSQL and can't get that to connect either.

Comment: **MySQL**? Aside from one, all those dialogs say you are connecting to a **MSSQL**. Which is it?

Comment: Looks like it automatically changed it to MSSQL because I didn't have the MySQL OBDC driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the ODBC driver for MySQL, not Microsoft SQL Server